# Is that possible to pass v-model ref to event handler

Tags: vue.js

I want to make a universal handler for input event and I need somehow to change v-model value in it. I tried this:

```
function validateInput(event) {
  let input = event.target.value;
  input = parseInt(input);
  if(isNaN(input)) {
    event.target.value = '';
  } else {
    event.target.value = input;
  }
}

<input @input="validateInput($event)"
  v-model="inputRef">
```

But `inputRef` doesn't react on `event.target.value` changes.

Comment: You're updating the event directly, this won't affect anything since the event has already beem emitted. You may want to update `inputRef` in your function instead

Comment: Also, you can use `input type="number"` to be sure you're dealing with numbers.

Comment: @Kapcash Yes, in perfect case I would like to change `inputRef` directly. In the code above I'm changing value of input and it works if there no v-model. Also, specifying type as number doesn't prevent user from inputing other characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Boussadjar mentioned, modifying `event.target.value` is no option.

just return the value from the event handler:

```js
function onlyNumbersFilter(event) {
  let input = event.target.value;
  input = parseInt(input);

  return isNaN(input) ? '' : input;
}
```

and use it:

```js
<input @input="inputRef = onlyNumbersFilter($event)" :value="inputRef">
```

Or if you want to stick with `v-model`:

```js
// setup
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'

// val is not DOM Event but value itself unwrapped from $event.target.value
function onlyNumbersFilter(val) {
  const n = parseInt(val);

  return isNaN(n) ? '' : val;
}

const filteredModel = function(valueRef, filterFn) {
  return computed({
    get() { return valueRef.value }
    set(newVal) { valueRef.value = filterFn(newVal)) }
  })
}

const input1Value = ref('')
const input1Model = filteredModel(input1Value, onlyNumbersFilter)

return {
  input1Model
}
```

and usage:

```js
<input v-model="input1Model">
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use `value` instead of `v-model` since `v-model` is the equivalent of `@input` ant `value` :

```html
function validateInput(event) {
  let input = event.target.value;
  input = parseInt(input);
  if(isNaN(input)) {
    inputRef.value = '';
  } else {
   inputRef.value = input;
  }
}

<input @input="validateInput($event)"
  :value="inputRef">
```

Comment: In that case value is undefined. How to pass it to handler?

Comment: are you using the composition api?

Comment: I mean `inputRef.value` instead of `value.value`

Comment: Yes, I'm using composition. If I will use inputRef in handler, it won't be universal anymore

Comment: what do you mean by universal?

Comment: I want to use this handler for different inputs with different v-models